# Angularjs data not displaying in view but I have it in console

Tags: angularjs

GET request:

```
$scope.customer = {};
$scope.view = function(id){
    $http.get(API_URL + "v1/customers/" + id)
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.customer = response.data;
            console.log($scope);
            $location.path('app/view-customer');
        },function error(response) {
            console.log('error');
            $scope.error = response.statusText;
        });
};
```

Logging the `$scope` or `$scope.customer` gives me the expected data however when trying to display it in the view im having no joy.

I have tried displaying it by just using:

```
{{ customer.fieldname }}
```

Output of `console.log(response.data)`

```
{custref: 105, resellerref: 33, channelref: 14, default_customer: "Yes", company: "edi Communications Limited", .....}
```

Have also tried to ng-repeat through the data and still no luck. Not sure what im doing wrong any help would be appreciated

Comment: Using any `controller` alias?

Comment: How does the response look like? Is there a property called "fieldname"?

Comment: Please share UI code also, otherwise its difficult to answer

Comment: paste the response.data

Comment: Also, why are you navigating to a different page `$location.path('app/view-customer');` if you want to display data on the current page?

Comment: No not using any alias @DhavalMarthak

Comment: What is the result of `response.data;` in console.log?

Comment: @Paflow fieldname is just an example, but yes the properties do exist. I will add response.data to question now

Comment: @RICKYKUMAR I have a list customers page which has a 'View' button. When clicked it opens a new view and displays more details than the list page. I will add that too if it helps

Comment: @Kyle  did u use controller name in view more details page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view is bound to the object created on first line i.e.

```
$scope.customer = {};
```

therefore when you reassign the `customer` variable, the view remained bind to the previous empty object and that's why it didn't change.

Try doing something like this:

```
$scope.info = {
    customer: {}
}
```

and access the customer object in the view as `info.customer.someProperty`.